# How to store additional data per user like session on Owin using Bearer Token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I need to store a token for thirdy party software calls on my controller after my client sign in, so I tried to save this on User Claims:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    private const string Token = "thirdyparty.token";
    private string Token
    {
        set
        {
            // Here I want to store a token in any way (Session, Cache, etc)
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claims = claimsIdentity.Claims;
            var tokenClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Token);

            if (Token != null)
            {
                claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(tokenClaim);
            }
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(Token, value));
        }
        get
        {
            // Here I want to get the token
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claims = claimsIdentity.Claims;
            var tokenClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Token);

            return tokenClaim?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

This did not work, my new Claim disappeared every time a new request is made.
So, how can I store some additional information per user?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the claims are part of the bearer token.

So even if you add the claim to the current identity the next request will 
have the old claim values as they are part of the token sent with the new request.

So, if you add a claim you need to generate a new token as well and return that to the client.

One way to generate a new token is to store the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions, used in the 
Startup.cs class, as a static variable and then use that where it's needed

```
public class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions { get; private set; }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        //....add the rest
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new AuthProvider() //Your derived OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Then to generate a new token

```
var claimsIdentity = ... //The claim identity after you have added the new claims
    var newToken = Startup.OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties()));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try it later. Is there any other way to solve this? Like storing the value of my new claim in a http header or cache or something like that?

Comment: And after creating a new ClaimIdentity, how can I return it from my api controller?

Comment: You could store the thirdyparty token in the response http header. Then you need to remember to add that value to the request header every time you do a new request to the api if you want to use it again.